# Zend Framework how to get the number of item in the loop ? partialLoop partialCounter and?

Tags: php, zend-framework, partial-views

I want to to make a particular processing for the last item of a `partialLoop`, the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) mention about `$this->partialCounter` but not the variable with the total number of items ...

```
<?php
if( $this->partialCounter == $mysteryvariable -1 ): 
?>
```

I am missing something I think ... cannot get my hand on that variable ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Zend_Registy::set('PartialCount', count($iterable));
$this->partialLoop($script,$iterable);
```

and then in your view

```
$count = Zend_Registy::get('PartialCount');
```

Fast and crappy, but working. Other way would be to to extend PartialLoop helper ;)

Comment: yeah I suspected I can use the Registry but that's really hacky, lucky in this case I count make it work by changing the position of the offending tag so could make a test like `if($this->partialCounter == 1)` but that not really satifying .. wondering why they don't put a partialTotal or something like that

Comment: other possibility is to inject the count to the iterabler object. Not array(0 => array('red' => 10), 1 =>array('red' => 5)); use array(0 => array('red' => 10, 'count' => 2), 1 =>array('red' => 5, 'count' => 2)); But that's also a hack and even more it's and less effective hack :D

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the total number of items, you will have to either extend Zend_View_Helper_PartialLoop to provide a method that returns the count of the iterable object being used by the PartialLoop.

Or, and I would say this is probably easier, just get the count of items in the object before you pass it into the PartialLoop since you have to pass either a Traversable object or an actual array into the PartialLoop helper and both implement support for count().

From the documentation:

```
<?php // partialLoop.phtml ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->key ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->value ?></dd>


<?php // MyController.php

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->$model = array(
                                 array('key' => 'Mammal', 'value' => 'Camel'),
                                 array('key' => 'Bird', 'value' => 'Penguin'),
                                 array('key' => 'Reptile', 'value' => 'Asp'),
                                 array('key' => 'Fish', 'value' => 'Flounder'),
                              );

        $this->view->modelCount = count($this->view->model); 
    }
```

From index.phmtl

```
<p>Count: <?= $this->modelCount ?></p>
<dl>
<?php echo $this->partialLoop('partialLoop.phtml', $this->model) ?>
</dl>
```

Comment: @gabriel1836: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean by pass it into the partialLoop? if you can write a small example

Comment: I need the count in the partial ^^ like the last item is different from other items (i.e. no ending span ... )

Comment: @RagZ - Are you saying that you want to know the current position of the array or iterable object and not just the total count of items in the array or object?

Answer (score 0):

I knew this is an old issue, but in ZF 1.12.1 this will be fixed. Till then there is a patch to get under following URL:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7151

Regards,
Sascha